# Che tipo di calciatore è uno che viene denominato "funambolo"?

Tags: word-meaning

Una volta, durante un allenamento di calcio, il mio allenatore mi ha dato del "funambolo". Ma cos'è esattamente un calciatore "funambolo"?

Answer (score 6):

Per [funambolo](http://www.treccani.it/vocabolario/funambolo/) si intende:

> 1. a. Chi cammina e fa giochi o esercizî sulla corda tesa, di solito a notevole altezza dal suolo; equilibrista.

Nel caso di un calciatore il termine prende una connotazione un po’ diversa, cioè di estrema abilità e velocità nel tocco di palla.

Si possono trovare in rete usi del termine riferiti a diversi campioni:

[Neymar è il miglior funambolo d’Europa davanti a Messi, ma in Italia il re è Douglas Costa](https://www.google.it/amp/s/calcio.fanpage.it/neymar-e-il-miglior-funambolo-d-europa-davanti-a-messi-ma-in-italia-il-re-e-douglas-costa/amp/)

[I NUMERI DEL CALCIO, il 7: le ali del pallone tra genio e sregolatezza](https://www.google.it/amp/www.itasportpress.it/calcio/i-numeri-del-calcio-il-7-le-ali-del-pallone-tra-genio-e-sregolatezza/amp/)

> Quando ancora i numeri facevano la storia, il 7 era l’ala destra:
>   **funamboli** sulla linea del fallo laterale, sfruttatori di praterie di
>   contropiede, le ali del pallone erano artisti e folli in un calcio
>   dove valeva la sola legge dell’uno contro uno: del centravanti contro
>   lo stopper, del trequartista contro il mediano, dell’ala contro il
>   terzino

Gli articoli fanno riferimento all’abilità nel dribbling, o meglio, nel saltare l’uomo, una delle capacità che riesce a mettere più in difficoltà le difese avversarie.

Direi che il tuo allenatore ti ha fatto un complimento, riconoscendo la tua spiccata abilità nel saltare l’uomo nell’uno contro uno.